# Prototype/TestFlight iOS application under personal account

Tags: app-store

I've been struggling to find an approach to a problem I have with registering an iOS based application with Apple.   I have an idea for a an iOS application that would require from Apple that the organization to be a registered 501c3.

What I *want* to do is develop the application under my personal developer account (I have apps in the store already through an LLC I have) to be able to test and prototype the idea fully with beta users via Test Flight and then if that shows promise go through the nightmare that is registering for a 501c3 entity with the IRS.   This process can take a long time from what I've read and is very complex and also there are significant costs involved (probably requires hiring an attorney/accountant to wade through all the paperwork).   So the bottom line is I  really don't want to go down the road of setting up a corporation, registering for non-profit status, yada yada if my app just isn't what it appears to be in my head when users have it in their hands.   I want to vet all the systems (which includes a fairly large backend admin web based application) prior to setting up the charitable organization.      In case anyone wants to know the app is going to accept donations via Apple Pay as a part of the application which Apple *requires* that you're a registered 501c3 otherwise I wouldn't go down this road at all.

I read the policies on transfer of apps, and contractor scenarios in the [Apple Enrollment documentation](https://developer.apple.com/support/enrollment/) but it doesn't really answer my questions about registering an App ID under one company (my personal account/LLC) but deploying the app under another entity after being fully tested.  FYI this isn't a contractor relationship as both organizations will be my own.    Also transferring seems to require that the App already be on the store as well as has severe limits to its entitlements (e.g. you can't use iCloud entitlements which my app will use) neither of which would work in my case.

Anyway - to recap I want to develop and beta test with users in Test Flight using my developer account and only after it's vetted put the App into the approval process after I get my 501c3 setup and registered so Apple can approve it's ability to accept donations via Apple Pay.   My concerns are mostly around technical issues related to this and/or how Xcode and entitlements/certifications/provisioning may cause issues.  e.g. if I develop and then register the application name in my personal account I'm under the impression this is globally unique so my 501c3 wouldn't be able to register that same name?

Thanks for any help!